# Пунктуация после "дожил"

Tags: пунктуация

— Дожил: разговариваю с птицами. (Пишется двоеточие, потому что в 2 части БСП идет пояснение, раскрытие смысла первой.)

— Разговариваю с птицами — дожил. (Ставится тире, т. к. в 2 части БСП идет следствие, результат.)
Все верно?

Answer (score 1):

Да, двоеточие обозначает пояснение. Но можно по-разному оформить.

**Дожил: разговариваю с птицами!**

**Дожил - разговариваю с птицами!** 
**Дожил, разговариваю с птицами!**

**Дожил! Разговариваю с птицами!**

Однако тире в предложении: **"Разговариваю с птицами - дожил"** некорректно. Поскольку смысл получается такой: **"Разговариваю с птицами, поэтому дожил".**

Что касается двоеточия, хотя оно корректно, но лучше его не использовать. Двоеточие более книжный знак, оно употребляется при подчеркнутом пояснении, тогда, когда важно предупредить читателя, что дальше будет пояснение.

В нашем примере чисто разговорная конструкция, поэтому лучше обойтись без двоеточия.

Answer (score 1):

**Факт:** разговариваю с птицами. **Вывод:** дожил (до такого).

Оформление по классическим правилам:

1) **Дожил: разговариваю с птицами.** Пояснение (откуда такой вывод).

2) **Разговариваю с птицами — дожил.** Факт - вывод.

Comment: "Факт - вывод" Откуда это? Вы следуете Розенталю? Розенталь: *если вторая часть заключает в себе следствие, вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой части (между частями можно вставить слова поэтому, тогда), например: Я умираю – мне не к чему лгать (Тургенев); Не было никакой возможности уйти незаметно – он вышел открыто, будто идет на двор, и шмыгнул в огород (Фадеев); Достав из кармана одновременно и спички, и зажигалку, Крайнев зажег шнуры – они вспыхнули (Попов).*. Но ведь это не наш случай. У нас нелья вставить слова поэтому, тогда.

Comment: Вывод - это не следствие, союз ПОЭТОМУ здесь не подходит.  Розенталь: 9. Если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения представляет собой присоединительное предложение, перед ней ставится тире (возможно вставить слово это, которое иногда имеется в самом предложении): На стене ни одного образа — (это) дурной знак (Л.) Похоже на факт-вывод?

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того, какой смысл Вы хотите вложить.

Дожил: разговариваю с птицами. ("Дожил", а именно ... Пояснение, раскрытие смысла того факта, что "дожил".)

Дожил — разговариваю с птицами. ("Дожил", так что теперь разговариваю с птицами. Следствие того, что описано в первой части.)

---

Разговариваю с птицами. Дожил. (Вывод помещаем после точки.)

Разговариваю с птицами: дожил. (Разговариваю с птицами, потому что "дожил". Вторая чать указывает на причину того, что описано в первой части.)

---

Не согласен с утверждением, что здесь во второй части идет следствие, результат: "Разговариваю с птицами - дожил." Разве дожил — следствие того, что я разговариваю с птицами?  Я не вижу в этом предложении приемлемого смысла.

Comment: @M_Г, а какой смысл вы вкладывете в предложении "Разговариваю с птицами - дожили"? Если  тире указывает на причину, следствие.

Comment: @Серж, Я не вижу в этом предложении приемлемого смысла.

Comment: @М-Г, вот и я не вижу. О чем и пишу.

Comment: Не видите смысла? Ну ваще... Смысл в том, что человек сбрендил и сам это осознает.